# Send an email in the future, without notification

Tags: ios, email

Is it possible on iOS to send an email in the future, by setting a time and date, without notification? Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 2):

YES it is possible. But for that you need to create a web service which will send mail on behalf of user with his/her notification.

Create web service, pass details for mail and send mail from there only is the only solution if you don't want to notify user or don't want to use [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for sending mails.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from an other server, you need a web server with php and mysql, you create a webservice, and send the "email" to the server, save it in the database with the subject, body and the date you want to send the email.

Than o the server you set up a cronjob that will run at specific intervals and check each email in the database to see if it's the time to send it, if so will send the email,

Basically this is the only solution you can have in this case, the user will think that he sent the mail, but the email will be sent later by the web server, not by the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Use local Scheduling Local Notifications and using this you can send mail as per your requirements.

[Scheduling Local Notifications](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/)

Hope, this will help you..